# owl-date-time double click event not working

Tags: angular, owl-date-time

I m trying to put a double click event on owl-date-time, so user can pick a date and set it with double click on the date. So far any kind of click event not working on date picker. I put (dblclick)="close()" on owl-date-time element but its not being fired. Any ideas how to achieve this ?

```
 <input matInput [formControlName]="config.name"  [owlDateTime]="dtFrom" (dateTimeChange)="valueChanged($event)"
        [placeholder]="config.placeholder + ' (from)'" [selectMode]="'rangeFrom'" autocomplete="off">
    <mat-icon [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dtFrom" matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;">
        {{ config.pickerType === 'calendar' ? 'date_range' : 'access_time' }}</mat-icon>
    <owl-date-time #dtFrom (dblclick)="close()" [pickerType]="config.pickerType ? config.pickerType : 'both'"></owl-date-time>
```